# Close a Popup when Tapped

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I close a Popup when someone Tapped it?

it is possible to set `IsLightDismissEnabled` to `true` but it will close the Popup when someone Tap somewhere else rather than the Popup itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event handler for `Tapped` in which you can `popup.IsOpen = false;`

the purpose of `IsLightDismissEnabled` is to close popup when it loses focus.